# Compute the gradient of a function in squared 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I have a function $f(x)$ in the $2$-norm

$$   f(x)= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \big\|Ax−b\big\|^2$$

How can i compute it's gradient?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the gradient of $||x||_2$ and $Ax$?

Comment: You might start by expanding this function as the sum of individual components of $x$. Then, the gradient is the vector containing the partial derivatives. This is a (long) but necessary way to compute the gradient if this is the first time you encounter it.

Comment: Nope @GáborPálovics i'm really new on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the chain rule. Notice that $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $h(x) = Ax - b$ and $g(u) = \frac12 \| u \|^2$. The derivatives of $g$ and $h$ are
$$
g'(u) = u^T \quad \text{and} \quad h'(x) = A.
$$
By the chain rule,
$$
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = (Ax - b)^T A.
$$
If we use the convention that $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector, then
$$
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = A^T(Ax - b).
$$

Comment: Ok thanks you so much, all clear!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$[\text{grad } f(x)]_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x)~~~~ (1)$$
$$[Ax]_i = \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j ~~~ (2)$$
$$ ||x||_2^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 ~~~ (3)$$
, where $[v]_i$ denotes the i-th component of the vector $v$

Example to use this
$$[\text{grad } ||x||_2^2]_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_j x_j^2 =  \sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_j^2 = \sum_j 2x_j \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} = \sum_j 2x_j \mathbb I\{i=j\} = 2 x_i $$
$$ \text{grad } ||x||_2^2 = 2[x_1, x_2, ...] = 2 x$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple but labor-intensive way is to develop the expression $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big\|Ax-b\big\|^2$ as follows and then calculate the partial derivatives.
\begin{align}
f(x)= 
& 
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big\|Ax-b\big\|^2
\\ 
=& 
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big\langle Ax \;\big|\; Ax\big\rangle
- \big\langle Ax \;\big|\; b\big\rangle
+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big\langle b \;\big|\; b\big\rangle
\\ 
=& 
\frac{1}{2}\cdot 
\Big\langle (A_{ij})_{m\times n}\cdot(x_{i1})_{n\times 1}
\;\Big|\;
(A_{ij})_{m\times n}\cdot(x_{i1})_{n\times 1}\Big\rangle
\\ 
&\qquad\qquad
-
\Big\langle (A_{ij})_{m\times n}\cdot(x_{i1})_{n\times 1}
\;\Big|\;
(b_{i1})_{m\times 1} \Big\rangle
+
\frac{1}{2}\cdot 
\Big\langle (b_{i1})_{n\times 1}
\;\Big|\;
(b_{i1})_{m\times 1} 
\Big\rangle
\\ 
=& 
 \frac{1}{2}\cdot 
 \Big\langle 
 \Big(\sum_{p=1}^{n}A_{ip}\cdot x_{p1}\Big)_{m\times 1}
 \;\Big|\;
 \Big(\sum_{q=1}^{n}A_{iq}\cdot x_{q1}\Big)_{m\times 1}
\Big\rangle
 \\ 
 &\qquad\qquad
 -
 \Big\langle 
 \Big(\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}A_{i\ell}\cdot x_{\ell 1}\Big)_{m\times 1}
 \;\Big|\;
 (b_{i1})_{m\times 1} 
 \Big\rangle
 +
\frac{1}{2}\cdot 
\Big\langle (b_{i1})_{m\times 1}
\;\Big|\;
(b_{i1})_{m\times 1} 
\Big\rangle
\\
=&
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{p=1}^{n}\sum_{q=1}^{n}
A_{ip}\cdot x_{p1}\cdot A_{iq}\cdot x_{q1}
-
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{\ell=1}^{m}
A_{i\ell}\cdot x_{1\ell}\cdot b_{1 i}
+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_{1i}b_{1i}
\end{align}

Comment: (You know it’s like a two line calculation with the chain rule right?)